# Is my exercise routine healthy?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, strength, exercise-technique, health

I read a few guides concerning push up programs and training the belly muscles and started my own routine, based on what I read. However I also read in this SE that an unbalanced training (e.g. only push ups) can be unhealthy.

I'm a fairly active person, I try to run 5-7 km once or twice o week. The idea of my training is just to keep in shape, not to achieve any particular weight loss/muscle building goals. My morning routine consists of:

- Weider's Series for the belly everyday:
  http://www.300situps.com/additional-information/various-types-training/weider-6-pack-training
  (but not the whole program - just the idea of the exercises, 
  which I progressively prolong if I get used to a previous setting - right now I'm doing 8 series)
- Push ups every other day:

7 push ups | 1 min holding in "down" push up position | 1 min break |

8 push ups | 1 min holding in the "up" push up position | 1 min break |

7 push ups | 1 min holding in the "down" push up position | 1 min break |

7 push ups | 1 min holding in the "up" push up position | 1 min break |

8 push ups | 1 min holding in the "down" push up position | 1 min break |

When I'll get comfortable with this setting, I plan on adding +1 push up to every series.

So my question is: is this an OK training routine and should I be worried of any balance/spine/general health issues? If yes, then what do you suggest I should change/add? I'll be very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more details on 'Weider's Series for the belly' or your variation thereof. That would make it easier to answer your question, as potential answerers won't have to google it first that way.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla It's one of the most popular belly routines in Poland, so I thought it's known everywhere... I added a link with pictures and description.

Comment: The biggest balance issue I see is that you train an upper body pushing movement, but no upper body pulling movement. Since I'm a huge pull-up nerd I'd suggest doing those, although rows would do just as well. If optical balance is a concern to you, you might want to train your legs a bit more, preferably with some (hill) sprints sprinkled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routine could probably use more cardio exercise.  5-7 km once or twice a week-while better than nothing-isn't much and does very little to improve or maintain your fitness.  A decent running routine for maintaining fitness might be to work on doing 30 minutes a day 3-4 times a week.

The rest of your routine looks better.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with that, maybe you should run more often, and around 20 or 30 minutes...
I personnally love jumping rope because not everybody can run everywhere, and in the city it's not always good with car pollution & co...

Something else : rather than "old up at the up phase" on some series, clap in your hands at the up "push-up position" seems to me a better choice.

### I explain

Old up is not going to really work something, while clap in your hands gonna work your cardio, your pectoral muscles and triceps at your landing with your inertia.. But not only that ! That will work your back too if you contract it (latissimus dorsi and quadratus lumborum)

Comment: I disagree on that a static hold of either push-up position is not beneficial. Holding the push-up position has all the benefits of a plank (working the core) but also trains the arms, shoulders and chest in an isometric fashion.

Comment: yeah, but all of this job will be done with the obligation to resist the inertia, and i've precise for the "up position" and not the "down position".
i've correct my post for this misunderstood

Comment: I don't see how holding the 'up' phase differs from holding the 'down' phase in any significant way. Unless you'd lock your elbows in the 'up' phase, which would be bad form, anyway.

Comment: that will stretch pectoral muscles, work rhomboides muscles, work triceps brachii, and with all of that, work thoracic diaphragm with a much better way.
but you are right, that's nothing

Comment: Yes I could have written that more clearly. Of course there's a differing focus on the muscles involved. What I meant to say was that I don't see how holding one position is a good exercise while the other isn't. As far as I can see, both are beneficial and there's no reason to keep one and switch out the other. But I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on that one.

Comment: You have convince me :d
(just in my mind, in the down phase, the muscular work is more important / intensive)